# Use User Local Setting To Display Date Under Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, grails, groovy

i have a grails project

```
Customer customer = Customer.get(params.id)
```

where customer is a domain class

i need to display

```
Date date = customer.createDate
```

in user local setting

i can use ***java*** or ***grails*** or ***groovy*** or ***html*** or ***javascript*** to do that

**Example:**

```
if date  = "2012-01-01 00:00:00.0" in GMT
then user must display it as "2012-01-01 01:00:00.0" in London (GMT +1)
```

any help to use user local setting to display date?

Comment: Not sure you can detect that automatically: HTTP doesn't convey timezone information... This is probably why many sites ask for it, so that they can display time accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show this site http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript it is helpful

download jstz.min.js and add a function to your html page

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getTimezoneName() {
        timezone = jstz.determine_timezone()
        return timezone.name();
    }
</script>
```

and call this function your  tag

Answer (score 0):

Java has the [`java.text.DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class to format dates. You'll have to pass the user's `Locale` to get an instance, in order to display the date in the user's preferred language. And you'll have to set the user's `TimeZone` to the DateFormat to display the date in the user's time zone.

Comment: how can i do that by code? how can i pass the user's Locale to get an instance?

Comment: The user's locale can be guessed from the HTTP request. See the grails documentation for this: they must have something to get it. For the timezone, you'll have to let the user choose his timezone explicitely, because it's not possible to get it from the request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Grails framework, I would suggest you have a look at [g:formatDate](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) tag. It lets specify the format as well as the locale (Internally it uses SimpleDateFormat).

Comment: g:format tag has many attributes on of them is locale, how can i pass to this attribute the locale of the user? there is also timezone attribute, how can i add user timezone value to this attribute?

Comment: By default it should pick the locale of the user. You can change the locale settings of your browser and see it in action. You can also get the locale explicitly by calling org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)

Comment: [how can i pass to this attribute the locale of the user?] this is my mean question, i try to solve this by using your answer but g:formatDate local attribute by default didn't take the user local settings. what shell i do to get user local?

Comment: You don't have to pass the locale explicitly. It should pick up the locale automatically and display the date accordingly.

Comment: how can i do that? i try but i couldn't display dates according to user local setting (his/her timezone)

Answer (score 0):

some dummy codes as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG, Locale.CHINA).format(customer.createDate()).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: i need to pass user locale if i use this it must be always Locale.CHINA

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already know the user's time zone, then you'll need some client side JavaScript to pass that information to your server.

```
var   d =new Date();
d.getTimezoneOffset();   //  send this value to the server
```

Use the timezone offset to select a time zone, and use that time zone when formatting the date, as other answers explain.

Actually, on second thought, there may be an easier way to satisfy your requirements.  If you want to format the date on the server side, as I mentioned above, let me know.  Otherwise, this method might be much, much simpler...

If your formatted string should always read YYYY-MM-DD..., then include the following code in the page's  section:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language='JavaScript'>
       <!--
        function formatDate(millis) {
           var      d =new Date(millis);
           return d.getFullYear() +"-" +(d.getMonth() +1) +"-" +d.getDate() +" " +d.getHours() +":" +d.getMinutes() +":" +d.getSeconds() +"." +d.getMilliseconds();
           }
    // -->
</script>
```

Then, wherever in the page you need the formatted date, include the following JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language='JavaScript'>
<!--
    document.write(formatDate(XXXX));
// -->
</script>
```

Replacing XXXX with the date, in milliseconds.  For instance, if you are generating the page using JSP, then in your Java code, use

```
request.setAttribute("dateInMillis", date.getTime());
```

and then in your JSP, use the JavaScript from above, replacing XXXX as follows:

```
document.write(formatDate(${dateInMillis}));
```

Comment: this works fine with new date, but i need to pass a variable that i got it from the database, to convert it to date as user local settings(timezone), i try these functions but the date display still as it is in the database while i try to access this project from different machines with different local settings

Comment: In the Java code (request.setAttribute(...)), date can be any Date you want - the current Date, or a Date pulled from your database.  Any Date I use displays converted for the client machine's time zone.  If this isn't working for you, please precisely describe the problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`<g:formatDate />`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) tag in Grails. In your controller you can call it as g.formatDate() method. I think it uses current user locale for rendering date.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently built a Grails plugin that makes use of the jstz javascript library to solve this for you:

https://grails.org/plugin/timezone-detection